# Camel validation against xsd: cannot find the declaration of element 'Address'

Tags: spring-boot, xsd, apache-camel

I want to make camel validation against a xsd, but i get an error:

> Cannot find the declaration of element 'Address'

I made this problem on smaller xml/xsd files.

validation.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="HouseNo" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

xml question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Address>
    <Street>string</Street>
    <HouseNo>string</HouseNo>
</Address>
```

camel config:

```
@Component
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet") // configure we want to use servlet as the component for the rest DSL
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json_xml) // enable json/xml binding mode
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true") // output using pretty print
                .contextPath("/c/api/")
                .apiContextPath("/api-doc")  // enable swagger api
                .apiProperty("api.version", "2.0.0")
                .apiProperty("api.title", "I")
                .apiProperty("api.description", "I")
                .apiProperty("api.contact.name", "A")
                .apiProperty("cors", "true"); // enable CORS

        // error handling to return custom HTTP status codes for the various exceptions
        onException(StartProcessException.class)
                .handled(true)
                // use HTTP status 400 when input data is invalid
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(400))
                .setBody(simple("Invalid input data"));

        rest()
                .description("I")
                .consumes("application/xml").produces("application/xml")
                .post("/start").type(Address.class)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json_xml).description("S")
                .route().routeId("I").log("Message send: \n ${body}")
                .to("validator:file:src/main/resources/validation.xsd")
                .endRest();
    }
}
```

Error is:

> org.apache.camel.support.processor.validation.SchemaValidationException:
>   Validation failed for:
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.SimpleXMLSchema@79c47167
>   errors: [ org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the
>   declaration of element 'Address'., Line : 2, Column : 10

Address DTO class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="Address")
@ToString
public class Address {
    @XmlElement(name = "Street", required = true)
    protected String street;
    @XmlElement(name = "HouseNo", required = true)
    protected String houseNo;
    // getters, setters
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct because your XML is not valid according to your schema. You have declared a **complex type** `Address` but the validation is looking for an **Element** `Address`.

Fix your schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Address">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="HouseNo" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Alternatively i could add ```<xs:element name="Address" type="Address"/>``` at the bottom (next to complex type definition). Not sure which is better.

Comment: Keeping the complex type separated from the element is better or even needed if you want to **reuse the complex type**. If you know that a complex type is unique and therefore used only once you can make it **kind of private or encapsulated** if you define it embedded in the element.